# Can i use checkSession with SAML?

Tags: auth0

Is using checkSession compatible with SAML type redirect flows? With renewAuth, I used to be able to pass redirectUri and usePostMessage to do silent auth callback. But does not seem to be working with checkSession. I'm using the latest auth0.js.

Answer (score 2):

`checkSession` itself uses OIDC/OAuth2 (as do all the authentication-related features of Auth0.js). But that's the protocol between the application and Auth0. 
The upstream connection can use any of the available protocols (including SAML) because in the `checkSession` flow Auth0 will not go to the upstream identity provider, relying instead on the Auth0 session.

If this is not working, might be work looking into other reasons. Check the console for errors, as well as the actual HTTP response from Auth0.